# WPF Prism.Unity - how to construct a ViewModel using named dependency injection

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

Using `Prism` 7.1, I can register two named dependencies:

```
containerRegistry.Register<ICustomersService, CustomersFakeService>("One");
containerRegistry.Register<ICustomersService, CustomersFakeService>("Two");
```

Now - how can I use any of them in `ViewModel` constructor?

```
public CustomersViewModel(ICustomersService customersService, EventAggregator eventAggregator)
```

throws an exception:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   'WPFPrismDI.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel', name = '(none)'. Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   WPFPrismDI.Services.ICustomersService, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:    Resolving
>   WPFPrismDI.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel,(none)   Resolving parameter
>   'customersService' of constructor
>   WPFPrismDI.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel(WPFPrismDI.Services.ICustomersService
>   customersService, Prism.Events.EventAggregator eventAggregator)
>       Resolving WPFPrismDI.Services.ICustomersService,(none)

My implementation of the service:

```
public interface ICustomersService
{
    ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> CustomerGetAll();
}

public class CustomersDBService : ICustomersService
{
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> CustomerGetAll()
    {
        ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> returnValue = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>();

        returnValue.Add(new CustomerModel() { NameFirst = "DB", });

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now - how can I use any of them in `CustomersViewModel` constructor?

By injecting all of them:

```
public CustomersViewModel(ICustomersService[] customersServices, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
```

Comment: But how do you tell one from another then?

Comment: You can't. That's the nature of them implementing the same interface. But you can put something in the interface to make them distinguishable, like a `string Source { get; }` property. Or, alternatively, you can inject only one, and assign one to your view model upon registration.